# Angular router link with replaceurl - avoid creating duplicate history in browser history

Tags: angular, angular-router, browser-history

I'm using Angular router's `NavigationBehaviorOptions.replaceUrl` nav option to ensure a transient url is not kept in the users browser history.

However, if a user happens to navigate to the url they were at immediately before navigating to the transient url, they end up with duplicate urls in the browser history. The impact is that then the user has to navigate twice to move past their current location.

How can i either:

1. Avoid creating the duplicate at all (using Angular api or browser) or
2. Detect and skip the duplicate url when the user navigates with the browser back/fwd buttons.

I expected Angular to handle this automatically but not the case unfortunately.